# Java how to compare two generic type parameters

Tags: java, generics, comparison, type-parameter

The problem is to write generic method, with T constrained to extends Number. Only have a single field variable ArrayList. Have an add method that adds objects to the ArrayList, and then two methods, one that returns the largest in the ArrayList and the other the smallest. My problem is in the largest and smallest methods where I am comparing successive items in the list with each other searching for the largest and smallest, but they are of generic type T and I cannot use < and >, and compareTo() does not work either (I put both errors in the code provided). Can someone take a look and let me know where I am going wrong?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyList<T extends Number> {
   private ArrayList<T> list;
   
   public MyList() {
      list = new ArrayList<T>();
   }
   
   public void add(T obj) {
      list.add(obj);
   }
   
   public T largest() {
      boolean onFirstObj = true;
      T largestVal;
      
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
         if (onFirstObj) {
            largestVal = list.get(i);
            onFirstObj = false;
         }
         else {
            if (list.get(i) > largestVal) {
               largestVal = list.get(i);
            }
         }
      }
      
      return largestVal;
   }
   
   public T smallest() {
      boolean onFirstObj = true;
      T smallestVal;
      
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
         if (onFirstObj) {
            smallestVal = list.get(i);
            onFirstObj = false;
         }
         else {
            if (list.get(i).compareTo(smallestVal) < 0) {
               smallestVal = list.get(i);
            }
         }
      }
      
      return smallestVal;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The < and > operators can only be used with primitive types, and the `Number` class does not implement `Comparable` itself, so you can't use compareTo.

However if you add `Comparable<T>` as a type bound:

```
public class MyList<T extends Number & Comparable<T>> {
    ...
}
```

then you can use the `compareTo` method:

```
public T largest() {
    boolean onFirstObj = true;
    T largestVal = null;

    for (T t : list) {
        if (onFirstObj) {
            largestVal = t;
            onFirstObj = false;
        } else {
            if (t.compareTo(largestVal) > 0) {
                largestVal = t;
            }
        }
    }

    return largestVal;
}
```

Comment: In my Gaddis Java book, that is the next question, modify the previous code to extend Comparable, so I am searching for a method that does not require adding Comparable as a type bound. Thanks, for the answer.

Comment: Interesting, is this perhaps an exercise that does not have a working example, and only serves as motivation for the next part as it shows why a type bound is needed?

Comment: Yeah, I think it is either that or it is simply an ill-posed question.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this.

Number has the methods for accessing primitive values (e.g. doubleValue()). So you can use `doubleValue()` for the compare to handle both integer and floating types.

It works because the `int, double, float and long methods` are declared `abstract` so any class that extends `Number` must provide implementations for them.  `byteValue()` and `shortValue()` are simply methods that call `intValue()` and are cast appropriately.

As mentioned in the comments, `BigInteger and BigDecimal` can have precisions that exceed what the `doubleValue` can accommodate so for those datatypes this
solution is destined to fail.

```
class MyList<T extends Number> {
    private ArrayList<T> list;
    
    public MyList() {
        list = new ArrayList<T>();
    }
    
    public void add(T obj) {
        list.add(obj);
    }
    
    public T largest() {
        T largestVal = list.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).doubleValue() > largestVal.doubleValue()) {
                largestVal = list.get(i);
            }
        }
        return largestVal;
    }
    

    
    public T smallest() {
        T smallestVal = list.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).doubleValue() < smallestVal.doubleValue()) {
                smallestVal = list.get(i);
            }   
        }
        return smallestVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the type `T` is `BigInteger` and it has a large value that cannot be represented by the precision of `double`, can it be processed correctly?

Comment: Probably not since the arbitrary precision of both `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` can exceed their primitive counterparts, and thus would also exceed what they can return in their implementations of the primitive methods in `Number`. Ultimately, implementing `Comparable` would be the way to go.  I was just demonstrating a possible, intermediate alternative.  But you raise a good point and I will emend my answer to mention it.